# Hide db's password with multiple git repository in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github, capistrano

I have a git repository both on GitHub and on my private Amazon instance and with a unique commit I update both.

There is a way to commit the file `database.yml` only to my private repository and not on GitHub?

If could help, I'm using Capistrano for deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past days I found no answer to this question, but then I solved my problem, so I'll say what I've done to have things working.

Since I don't have to modify the file `database.yml`, I solved my problem manually copying it to my Amazon instance and adding it to `.gitignore`.

Then, I added a task in `deploy.rb` to link `database.yml` to the current directory of deployment

```
# copy db config
after "deploy:update_code", :copy_db_config
desc "copy db config file"
task :copy_db_config do
  run "ln -s ~/path/where/I/copied/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end
```

Hope this help.

Comment: That's also what I have been doing: http://www.tigraine.at/2011/09/25/securely-managing-database-yml-when-deploying-with-capistrano/

Comment: @Tigraine Great :) Unfortunately I didn't see your post in the past days.. I could have save _a lot_ of time

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151324/securely-providing-the-database-password-in-a-rails-app). If you previously define environment variables you can use them in the `databases.yml` file.

```
username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USERNAME'] %>
password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
```