# How to use rake database commands with password

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, rake

Hello all I am trying to use a command -

```
rake db:migrate
```

but I am getting this as feedback in the terminal -

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I'm looking to have something to request the password when I use the command, such as

```
rake db:migrate -p
```

but this isn't working for me I've tried various things like putting it before rake, just after rake and using -u and root with it.

## My question is how do I make this command also prompt for the password when it tries to access the database, so it doesn't give me an error like this?

Comment: quick question, what environment are you in? dev? or production?

Comment: probably dev, im new to this so Im not too sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at your `config/database.yml` file to ensure you have your DB username and password set correctly.

Edit:

I also found a useful link which helps not storing your password in the `database.yml` file as plain text, you store it as an ENV variable which can then be defined before accessing your database using the terminal.

instructions are here :

[Securely providing the database password in a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151324/securely-providing-the-database-password-in-a-rails-app/27430244#27430244)

Comment: But im not looking to leave a password in plain text in that file id need to encrypt it somehow

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7306399/5786216) at this response to database.yml  I'm not sure what you're asking is possible. Rails will use the database.yml file to connect to your DB on your different environments; it shouldn't be committed.

Comment: @MarioNovello is correct, use `<%= ENV['YOUR_VAR_HERE'] %>` and set it in the server and don't commit it. In dev just use ur dev credentials.

Comment: Probably a newbie's question but what do you mean don't commit it? I understand what commit means just not what you mean by it?

Comment: I did this so the password isnt stored as plain text in the yml file - https://stackoverflow.com/a/27430244/7124969

Comment: I would like to add that you want to configure this for each database environment you are using, development, testing, and production. You can read about this in more detail [here](https://kolosek.com/rake-db-commands/).

Answer (score 0):

Go to app/config/database.yml
This file is responsible for databases connection configuration for various environment. ex. development, production etc.

ex.

```
 development:       

 adapter: mysql2

 encoding: utf8

 database:        #database name.

 username:        # mysql user name

 password:        # mysql Password

 host    :        # from where databases you asses from local or remote

                  remote you specify the remote server ip address.
```

You need set password correctly.